# Filling in a ton of NA data in R by indices?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have Price data indexed according to three things:

State, Date, and UPC (that is the Product Code).

I have a bunch of prices that are NA.

I am trying to fill the NAs in in the following way: For a given missing Price with index (S,D,UPC), fill in with the average Price of all the data points with the same S and UPC. I.e., take the average over Date.

There must be an incredibly easy way to do this because this is very simple. I have been using for loops, but I now realize that that is incredibly inefficient and I would like to use a function, such as one in plyr or dplyr, that will do it all in as few steps as possible.

```
upc=c(1153801013,1153801013,1153801013,1153801013,1153801013,1153801013,2105900750,2105900750,2105900750,2105900750,2105900750,2173300001,2173300001,2173300001,2173300001)
date=c(200601,200602,200603,200604,200601,200602,200601,200602,200603,200601,200602,200603,200604,200605,200606)
price=c(26,28,NA,NA,23,24,85,84,NA,81,78,24,19,98,NA)
state=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1)

# This is what I have:
data <- data.frame(upc,date,state,price)

# This is what I want:
price=c(26,28,27,27,23,24,85,84,79.5,81,78,24,19,98,47)
data2 <- data.frame(upc,date,state,price)
```

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this... I would appreciate if you just told me what I did wrong rather than passive aggressive links and thumbs down.

Comment: @ejn - it's not passive aggressive, those questions describe briefly what you need to provide for people to give you a reasonable answer. They are essentially the 'rules' of Stackoverflow which will help us help you.

Comment: I am creating a mock dataframe now to show you what I mean... I appreciate the patience, I'll be done in a mo.

Comment: Is that adequate? What else do I need?

Comment: Just learn how to ask a good question and don't be so aggressive. The example you provided is fine.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice!! You are all gentlemen and scholars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ave` with multiple grouping variables, and then replace `NA` values with the means:

```
with(data,
  ave(price, list(upc,state), FUN=function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),mean(x,na.rm=TRUE) ) )
)
# [1] 26.0 28.0 27.0 27.0 23.0 24.0 85.0 84.0 79.5 81.0 78.0 24.0 19.0 98.0 47.0
```

Answer (score 6):

You can construct a matrix of means by upc and state:

```
meanmtx <- tapply(dat$price, dat[c('upc','state')], mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

That matrix has character indices that can be matched to values in `upc` and `state`. So then use 2 column character indexing to put these in the empty "slots":

```
dat$price[is.na(dat$price)] <-  
          meanmtx[  cbind( as.character(dat[  is.na(dat$price), 'upc']), 
                           as.character(dat[  is.na(dat$price),'state']) )  ]

> dat
          upc   date state price
1  1153801013 200601     1  26.0
2  1153801013 200602     1  28.0
3  1153801013 200603     1  27.0
4  1153801013 200604     1  27.0
5  1153801013 200601     2  23.0
6  1153801013 200602     2  24.0
7  2105900750 200601     1  85.0
8  2105900750 200602     1  84.0
9  2105900750 200603     2  79.5
10 2105900750 200601     2  81.0
11 2105900750 200602     2  78.0
12 2173300001 200603     1  24.0
13 2173300001 200604     1  19.0
14 2173300001 200605     1  98.0
15 2173300001 200606     1  47.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another compact option using `na.aggregate` (from `zoo`) and `data.table`.  The `na.aggregate` by default replace the `NA` values with the `mean` of the column of interest.  It also has a `FUN` argument in case we want to replace the NA by `median`, `min` or `max`, or whatever we wish.  The group by operations can be done by dplyr/data.table/base R methods.  With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'upc', 'state', we assign (`:=`) the 'price' as the `na.aggregate` of 'price'.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(data)[,  price:= na.aggregate(price) , .(upc, state)]
```